# Input resistance and mid-band gain of a CE-CE stage cascade amplifier

Tags: amplifier, bjt, resistance

I am trying to calculate the input resistance and mid-band gain of a CE-CE stage.

Here's what I got so far:

[image]

I am having some doubts regarding my calculations though, mainly about the input resistance. Can we really ignore the second transistor when calculating Rin?

Comment: Did you calculate the DC operating points for both transistors? What is the base-emitter voltage for the 2nd transistor?

Answer (score 0):

What I've learned, the input resistance in emitter circuit \$ r_e \approx r_{BE} = \beta U_T / I_C \$, the \$  U_T \$ is the temperature voltage of about 26 mV at room temperature. More precisely: $$ U_T = kT/e_0 = \frac{1.38\cdot10^{-23} \text{ J/K} \cdot 296 \text{ K}}{1.60\cdot 10^{-19}\text{ C}} = 25.5 \text{ mV}$$
The output doesn't influence the input resistance so much and can be neglected in that emitter circuit.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. What about the gain though? Is it really just double the gain of a single CE?